# Why do I get the Corrupt JPEG data error when I run Motion?

Tags: 10.04, webcam

I have Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit and Logitech HD C270 webcam.

When I run Motion (as root or normal user), I get this output:

```
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.11 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3412993 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3415808
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] cap.driver: "uvcvideo"
[1] cap.card: "UVC Camera (046d:0825)"
[1] cap.bus_info: "usb-0000:00:1d.7-4.1"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x04000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - STREAMING
[1] Supported palettes:
[1] 0: YUYV (YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV))
[1] 1: MJPG (MJPEG)
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.11 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8080
[1] index_format 2 Test palette MJPG (320x240)
[1] Using palette MJPG (320x240) bytesperlines 0 sizeimage 51200 colorspace 00000008
[1] VIDIOC_G_JPEGCOMP not supported but it should be (does your webcam driver support this ioctl?)
[1] found control 0x00980900, "Brightness", range 0,255 
[1]     "Brightness", default 128, current 128
[1] found control 0x00980901, "Contrast", range 0,255 
[1]     "Contrast", default 32, current 32
[1] found control 0x00980902, "Saturation", range 0,255 
[1]     "Saturation", default 32, current 32
[1] found control 0x00980913, "Gain", range 0,255 
[1]     "Gain", default 0, current 0
[1] mmap information:
[1] frames=4
[1] 0 length=51200
[1] 1 length=51200
[1] 2 length=51200
[1] 3 length=51200
[1] Using V4L2
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
```

Followed by this error:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd3
[1] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd4
[1] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
Corrupt JPEG data: 3 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
[1] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
Corrupt JPEG data: 4 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd2
[1] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
```

The answer might lie in this line from the first part of the output:

```
[1] VIDIOC_G_JPEGCOMP not supported but it should be (does your webcam driver support this ioctl?)
```

Comment: It is very bad manners to refuse to help someone with a problem. This error *is* reproducible and occurs not only with this Logitech camera. I would have loved to find a solution here, but it was blocked by some people who believe to be helpful and intelligent  by telling others that their question is off-topic. They are not!

Comment: Yeah Bum-buntu!